# Android Button or onTouchEvent

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm making an android game with SurfaceView and I need to handle touch events.

I tried `onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)` and it worked except for making buttons.

If there is an `onTouchFinishEvent()` type thing, that would be useful for making a button. Or instead should I use an Android button (with a transparent texture) and if so what's the best way.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
           //touch start
           break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
           //touch finish
           break;
    }
}
```